# java localized date with short date pattern

Tags: java, date

For the code below:

```
public class DateFormatTest {

    @Test
    public void shouldTestDateFormat()  {

        DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, Locale.getDefault());
        System.out.println(df.format(new Date()));

        df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, Locale.GERMANY);
        System.out.println(df.format(new Date()));
    }
}
```

The output is :

```
2/1/16
01.02.16
```

How do I get the output bellow instead of the previous:

```
2/1/2016
01.02.2016
```

Note: The regional settings for short date are: English(US) , MM/dd/yyyy.

I need the output above when I change the locale not the short date pattern. I don't need to care for all the patterns in the world. The code simulates the change of the locale:

```
    localize(Locale.getDefault());
    localize(Locale.GERMANY);

private void localize(Locale locale) {
    DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, locale);
    System.out.println(df.format(new Date()));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code is not guaranteed to work, but unfortunately it's the only way I know, and it works with Oracle's implementation of Java 7 & 8. If it doesn't work, it will print a 2-digit year instead.

```
private static void printLocalizedDate(Locale locale) {
    DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, locale);
    if (df instanceof SimpleDateFormat)
        df = new SimpleDateFormat(
                ((SimpleDateFormat) df).toPattern().replace("yy", "yyyy")
        );
    System.out.println(df.format(new Date()));
}

    printLocalizedDate(Locale.getDefault());
    printLocalizedDate(Locale.GERMANY);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 public static void main(String args[]){  
     Date dNow = new Date( );
     SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("M/d/yyyy", Locale.GERMAN);

     System.out.println("Current Date: " + ft.format(dNow));

     ft = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy", Locale.GERMAN);
     System.out.println("Current Date: " + ft.format(dNow));

}
```

use `SimpleDateFormat`

**output** :

```
Current Date: 2/1/2016
Current Date: 01.02.2016
```

Comment: I don't need to keep track for all the patterns in the world. I just need to change the locale.

Answer (score 0):

You could create the format string yourself:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("M/d/yyyy");
System.out.println(df.format(new Date()));

df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
System.out.println(df.format(new Date()));
```

With those format-strings (`M/d/yyyy` and `dd.MM.yyyy`) you can define the output by yourself as you wish it to be.

In this case:

- `d` displays the day-of-month without leading 0
- `dd` displays the day-of-month with leading 0
- `M` and `MM` are equivalent to `d` & `dd` displaying the month
- `yyyy` displays the year in a 4-digit representation

Comment: I could not simulate the change of the locale.